# How to add Header in ListView at specific location and create custom view for list item

Tags: android, listview

i am again here with one issue 
i want to crate a custom view of list item with imageview and textview's and also i need to add header's on specific positions. i never used sectioned listview yet. 
 I need to add more than one `textview and imageview` in listitem and also i need to add `header's` at some random positions. please help me in solving this. i had googled it and i found some examples also but i am unable to `customize` it.

Thanks in advance.
Mahaveer.

Answer (score 2):

I understood it a little bit. You should add more attribute like `header` in your model.

If your `header` = **true** and in your `adapter` class, then you have to inflate the layout `header.xml`. Otherwise, if `header` = **false**, then you should inflate your xml file i.e. (`TextView`,`ImageView`) as normal.

Here `separator` in my code is the same as your `header`

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            final recordModel model = records.get(position);
            ViewHolder holder;
             convertView = null;
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            if(records.get(position).getSeparator()==0){
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.record_row, null);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                    holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView
                                    .findViewById(R.id.iconCallType);
                    holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
                    holder.note = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.note);
                    holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.check_box);
                   ..........................
            }else if(records.get(position).getSeparator()==1){
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.separator, null);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                    holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSeparator);
                    holder.title.setText(records.get(position).getCallDay());
            }


            return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: actually i need to add header dynamically that means m fetching data from server so i need to add header at random position and i don't know how to add it dynamically. and my list item is custom includes textview and imageview thanks for help.

Comment: if you add models with 'header' = true randomly to your array of data. It will show header randomly in your listview...

Answer (score 1):

We do have a lot of amazing tutorials for the same, check some examples below:-

1. [Android Section List](http://code.google.com/p/android-section-list/)
2. [Android Amazing ListView](http://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/)

Do let us know, if you have to deal anu issue while doing it or have to go for any specific requirements to complete it.

Comment: i gone through these examples and i am trying to customize it. thanks for help....

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own Header at any specific position using **[getItemViewType()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29)** and [**getViewTypeCount()**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getViewTypeCount%28%29). [**Here**](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296) is a nice blog that explain everything about using these methods.