# Android Listview with some non-standard columns

Tags: android

The picture below is a Listview row I am looking for. Its kind of Inventory list.

[image]

Question:

How do I draw/create this kind of a List view row 
where

1) The first column doesn't have horiz. or vert. splitter lines.

2) The second column one is kind of a box with both horz. and vert splitter lines.

There is a space between second and third column.

3) The third column a standard list view row with text and small icons in it.

How to combine all the 3 to make this a jazy row? :)

I do know how to make a listview with the 3rd column alone; with text and images. But the column spacing and the vertical lines are the ones I don't know.

Thank you for any suggestion

Jacob

Comment: Take a look at my post, I have solve this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811192/how-to-add-header-in-listview-at-specific-location-and-create-custom-view-for-li/10811630#10811630

Answer (score 2):

It's not too tricky to create a layout as shown as row layout for a `ListView`. I'll just help you on your way a bit. Do mind that you might want to make some improvements, for example, don't hardcode the size of the 'squares', but provide them from `dimens.xml` in your different screen density/size buckets.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <View android:layout_width="30dp" android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" android:background="@drawable/border_color_red" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:background="@drawable/border" android:gravity="center"
        android:text="QTY" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" android:padding="5dp">

        <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/star"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <CheckBox android:id="@+id/star" style="?android:attr/starStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/box_right"
            android:text=" " />

        <View android:id="@+id/box_right" android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border_color_red" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The `ListView` will need to hide its divider:

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:divider="@null">
        <!-- Preview: listitem=@layout/list_item_layout -->
    </ListView>
```

Borders are added using a simple `ShapeDrawable`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:height="1dp" android:width="1dp" android:color="#000" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
</shape>
```

Change the `solid` color to create a different fill color (e.g. for the squares).

The result will look somewhat like this:

[image: list item layout]

The biggest drawback is that there is not really a straightforward approach to get rid of the 'double' dividers inbetween the different rows. If it really bothers you, there's definitely a couple of ways you could work around them (e.g. inflate different layouts for the first and last item in your adapter, or add the first and last item as header and footer, or factor the lines out into separate views which you can then toggle, etc...).

I didn't add in the `ImageView` since that'll be pretty self-explanatory. Place it at the same position as the 'item' `TextView` and toggle between the two based on whether you want to display text or an image.

I'm assuming you'll be able to come up with a matching `Adapter` (and 'ViewHolder'/'RowWrapper') for the layout.

Drop a line if anything still isn't clear. :)

Comment: Thank you for the response; appreciate it very much. I only know about SimpleAdapter class. Can you please suggest a Android adapter example I should look to for the above task. Also, the above star checkbox is clickable. Can  the RED view box be made clickable? thanks again.

Comment: Examples are widespread, [here's one that looks pretty ok](http://goo.gl/2qXTy). To summarize, you'll want to store the data to present in the list in simple Java objects, which you then pass into the `Adapter`. Regarding the boxes: depending on the behaviour you're after, you could make those a `CheckBox` or `ToggleButton` for two states (on/off). If you need more complex behaviour, you're probably going to create/extend something yourself. If you don't want the widget to be clickable, simply set that attribute flag to false.

Answer (score 0):

I have made something similar using TableLayout and TableRow. It allows you to make "row-templates" in XML and then implement them as you want to in any order.

Say you have your activity use the layout main.xml:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Then you would inflate each row template as you need it:

```
     LayoutInflater myInflate = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
     row1 = (TableRow) myInflate.inflate(R.layout.matchesoverviewlistitem, null);

     // Here you can do anything you want with the table row elements
     tv = (TextView)row1.findViewById(R.id.matchesOverLabel);
     tv.setText("MyText");

     row1.setTag(n);
     row1.setOnClickListener(seriesListener);

     // Finally add the table row to the tableLayout
     myTable.addView(row1,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

This has worked fine for me when using different layouts for a number of rows.

Comment: thank you for the response; appreciate it; I will take both responses.