# Better way for header in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I want to show a fairly complex header above an ExpandableListView. The header basically holds some artwork and some text. When I scroll the List I want the header to scroll off the screen.

I can do it by adding a section to the list view with no children but it makes my BaseExpandableListAdapter very clunky. does anyone know of a better way. I've tried adding the header in the xml before the ExpandableListView tags but that makes it static at the top of the page when I scroll the ExpandableListView.

Comment: Like https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders or not sticky?

Comment: Not sticky... That's it own can of worms :).

Answer (score 1):

if you do not like native View header [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29) you can inflate  special view and return it in the first position in your Adapter.
Actually we make adapter to control getting view in our ListView. So you can always return special views in special positions and for me that is ok. Not always view in your ListView must be similar. You just need to implement some populating logic for all this views.

Good luck!

Comment: Sorry I am not sure I understand what you are saying. You created a separate adapter to insert a view in a specific position of a ListView? Also, if I use `addHeaderView()` will that inflated view scroll off the screen when user scrolls?

Comment: And if there are any reasons do not use it, yes - you can insert a view in a specific position of a ListView by your hands)

Comment: Do you mind showing me how to do the second option with a little bit of code? Just to point me in the right direction.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/10811630/1277018 this. But in your case you just check postion == 1 and if it is true, inflate your header view.